# .Value does not read whole string

Tags: excel, vba

In my macro I need to read a value out of a Cell. The values always start with an `'` followed by a number like `'1` or `'1001`.

When I attempt to read the cell like `s = wsout.Cells(headerVal(6, 1) + i, 1).Value`, I only get `1` instead of `'1`.

`wsout` is a worksheet and `s` is defined as a String.

How do I read the actual contents of the cell?

Comment: Maybe try text instead of value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [Range.PrefixCharacter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.prefixcharacter) Property whih returns the prefix character for the cell.

Here is an example

```
s = wsout.Cells(headerVal(6, 1) + i, 1).PrefixCharacter & _
    wsout.Cells(headerVal(6, 1) + i, 1).Value

Debug.Print s
```

If the cell has `'1` then `s` above will have `'1`